# Negative values in Pie chart in Jasper Reports

Tags: java, jasper-reports, jfreechart

I have a requirement to display negative values in pie chart in jasper reports.I am able to achieve this using customizer class.In createCustomizedDataset method I am checking if value is negative then later on while generating label I am appending "-" sign

```
PiePlot piePlot = (PiePlot) chart.getPlot();
    PieDataset dataset = piePlot.getDataset(); // line 1
    PieDataset dataset1 = createCustomizedDataset(dataset,piePlot);
    piePlot.setDataset(dataset1);

    StandardPieSectionLabelGenerator labelGen = new StandardPieSectionLabelGenerator(
            "{1}") {

        @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
        @Override
        public String generateSectionLabel(PieDataset dataset, Comparable key) {
            String label = super.generateSectionLabel(dataset, key);

            if(dataSetKeys.contains(key.toString())){
                return "-"+label;
            }else{
                return label;
            }
        }

    };
```

Output is below :

[image]

ISSUE IS : if there are multiple entries for negative values I am getting a different category with negative values combined.At line 1 the dataset key for these negative values is 'Other'.Here I have two categories one with value as "-2.02" and one with "-0.01". So instead of showing two slices it is showing one slice of 2.02+0.01=2.03.Problem is the dataset in customize method is like that.

[image]

Comment: If other is a sum of negative and postive values....it starts to have even less sense.... remove the value on the other slice ; ), or use other chart type to display data...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it resolved as in chat edit wizard minimum expression was set to 0.Remove that to solve the issue.